# Show existence of unit in a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring with right identity $e$. If for each $a \in R\setminus \{0\}$ there exists $x \in R$ such that $xa = e$. Show that $R$ is a division ring.

I can show this result for finite ring $R$, but finiteness is not given. Firstly I think considering $(ax - e)a$ would be enough to prove this, but now I realize only right identity condition is given.

Comment: I would give that as definition for division ring. What do you mean then?

Comment: To show division ring I have to show $ax = xa = e.$ But from above how can I show $ax = e?$

Comment: Ok, you are right. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course if $R=\{0\}$ everything is trivial (and $R$ isn't really a division ring) so we suppose this is not the case, and $e\neq 0$.

Suppose $ex-x\neq 0$ for some $x$. Then there exists $y$, such that $y(ex-x)=e$, but $y(ex-x)=yex-yx=yx-yx=0$, not $e$. By this contradiction, $ex=x$ for all $x$. So $e$ is a two-sided identity.

The rest follows the trivial routine: if $x\neq 0$, then $\exists y\neq 0$ such that $yx=e$. Then $\exists z$ such that $zy=e$. But $x=(zy)x=z(yx)=z$, so in fact $xy=e$ as well. All elements are invertible.